# I cant get rid of Request failed: bad request (400)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2, bad-request

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"project_name": @"hasanProj",
                             @"project_desc" : @"testing...",
                             @"project_date" : @"2015-2-22"
                             };

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://serverIP"]];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[HRUser sharedUser].userApiKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[manager POST:@"/rest/v1/project" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

This code is returning `Request failed: bad request (400)`.

I checked parameter, url they are all correct. I called it from chrome extension postman and getting correct result.

And other requests are working perfectly, even get is working fine.

But why I am getting `Request failed: bad request (400)` on this?

Comment: Does your server expect a Content-Type: application/json header?

Comment: yes server expect a Content-Type: application/json

Comment: but I have checked it by adding "[manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/json"]" but still same error.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same error and this worked for me..

```
   manager.responseSerializer.acceptableStatusCodes = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:400];
```

or

You can directly parse the response object.

Answer (score 2):

i think there will be problem with the request. your putting wrong type or wrong data.
acceptableContentTypes for request also matters.
second thing the parameters that your sending data to it. check tags correct are not
ask WEB service developer exact need of API.

**Code:**

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"project_name": @"hasanProj",
                             @"project_desc" : @"testing...",
                             @"project_date" : @"2015-2-22"
                             };

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]init];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[HRUser sharedUser].userApiKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

[manager.requestSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/json"];
[manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/json"];


[manager POST:@"http://serverIP/rest/v1/project" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) 
{
    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
}];
```